# the Gecko path is not working

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, testng, firefoxdriver

```
package firsttestngpackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.*;

public class FirstTextNGFile {

   public String baseUrl = "http://newtours.demoaut.com/";
   public WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

   @Test
   public void verifyHomepageTitle() {
      System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","c:\\geckodriver-v0.24.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
      driver.get(baseUrl);
      String expectedTitle = "Welcome: Mercury Tours";
      String actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
      Assert.assertEquals(actualTitle,  expectedTitle);
      driver.quit();
   }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You have an escape character in your driver path.  Try: ` "c:\\\\geckodriver-v0.24.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe"` instead.  If this fixes the problem, I will make it into an answer.

Comment: no, this did not help

Comment: Check the versions of both Firefox and Gecko.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Second post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version).  Also, if there is an exception being thrown, please add that to this post (the stack trace).

Comment: The same path was working for plain JAVA but is creating an error for testNG

Comment: Still need a stack trace then...

Comment: What is a stack trace?

Comment: Please find a solution

Comment: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property. this is what the error reads

Comment: Is the code crashing?  If it is, that error your see is the exception.  The stack trace shows you where it all went awry.

Comment: Second post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676719/selenium-using-java-the-path-to-the-driver-executable-must-be-set-by-the-webdr).

Comment: [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.3

Comment: Please include the full error message and more context. This will answering easier.

Answer (score 1):

Your code cannot work, you need to call

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","c:\\geckodriver-v0.24.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
```

Before

```
public WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Because the `new FirefoxDriver` creates a new instance and tries to find the geckodriver somewhere in your path, unless give it a specific path first. After this it will start the test code.

I would use the TestNG `[setUp()][1]` method to configure the driver before the test:

```
public class FirstTextNGFile {

 public WebDriver driver;

 @BeforeClass
 public void setUp() {
   System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","c:\\geckodriver-v0.24.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
   driver = new FirefoxDriver()
 }

 @Test
 public void verifyHomepageTitle() {
   // test code
 }
}
```